# How do I select multiple rows where one row has a specific value in a column?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a table with data as shown below. I need to create an SSRS report showing all submittals for a project when at least one submittal for the project has a status that contains 16.

Example data:

```
| Project | SubmittalNumber | Description | Status |
|---------|-----------------|-------------|--------|
|53613    |13-1             |Permit       |16A     |
|53613    |13-2             |Survey       |15      |
|53613    |13-3             |Hours        |14      |
|53674    |74-1             |Permit       |15      |
|53674    |74-2             |Survey       |14      |
|1063     |63-1             |Permit       |16      |
|1063     |63-2             |Survey       |13      |
```

The data I would expect to have returned:

```
| Project | SubmittalNumber | Description | Status |
|---------|-----------------|-------------|--------|
|53613    |13-1             |Permit       |16A     |
|53613    |13-2             |Survey       |15      |
|53613    |13-3             |Hours        |14      |
|1063     |63-1             |Permit       |16      |
|1063     |63-2             |Survey       |13      |
```

I know using Where Status LIKE '16%' will return only the rows with some version of 16, but not the the other rows related to the project. I've also found solutions with Exist, but that seems to apply when using data from 2 separate tables. I'm sure the solution is simple, but I haven't been able to find it. Can someone please assist?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `EXISTS` subquery with `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM T t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM T tt
    WHERE Status LIKE '16%' AND tt.Project = t1.Project
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select e.*
from example e
where exists (select 1
              from example e2
              where e2.Project = e.Project and 
                    e2.Status like '16%'
             );
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "contains".  The above interprets it as meaning "starts with".  If the `16` can appear anywhere, then use:

```
                    e2.Status like '%16%'
```